# Lazy Loading with react ag data grid

Tags: reactjs, datagrid, ag-grid, ag-grid-react, tingodb

I am working with `React Ag Grid`. I want to implement lazy loading with the grid.

But `React Ag Grid` does not provide lazy loading. It provides infinite scrolling but then it will not support filtering and sorting.

I am using `tingodb` (Nosql) db,

How can I achieve lazy loading with `react ag grid`?

TIA

Comment: See [ask], and especially [mcve]. The idea is you describe what you want to do, show what you tried, and tell us what results you get

Comment: Lazy loading is the same as infinite scrolling in this case. https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-infinite-scrolling/ says "The grid cannot do sorting or filtering for you, as it does not have all of the data. Sorting or filtering must be done on the Server-side.".

Comment: Ya I went through it, but I need to provide whole data to grid through datasource then it performs infinite scrolling. And providing whole data at once take time, i do not want to fetch whole data at once. 
Any way I can achieve this?

Comment: It doesn't "fetch [the] whole data at once". https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-infinite-scrolling/#getrows says: "The startRow and endRow define the range expected for the call. For example, if block size is 100, the getRows function will be called with `startRow: 0` and `endRow: 100` and the grid will expect a result with 100 rows (that's rows 0 to 99).". Your backend should only be returning the requested rows, not *every* row.

Comment: ok, so in that case I need to call API multiple times. right?